# VBS: FileSystemObject use in Recursion

Tags: recursion, vbscript, filesystemobject

Currently I'm working on a script that will go through a given folder and search for all files with a specific extension.  It will then print out the name and sum the file size.  I believe i have most of the issues sorted out, so this question isn't about how to do this.

Instead, I want to know what would be the best practice for using FileSystemObject streams in a recursive function.  Should I be using a single stream for all calls (either global, or passed), or should I be creating a new stream for each recursive step?

For extra fun, I'm planning on having this access multiple PCs, and over UNC path.  And yes, I expect there's a better way of doing this, but I'm relatively new with VBS.

Current code:

```
'Recursive Function handles search of files in folder and subfolders.
Function UNCSearchFolder(strUNCRootPath, strUNCNextFolder)  
 Dim objFSOUNCSearchFolder, objFSOUNCSearchFolder2, colFolderList, objFolder, strCurrentFolder, strSubFolder

 'Get list of Subfolders in folder: <Rootpath>\<Nextfolder>
 strCurrentFolder = strUNCRootPath & "\" & strUNCNextFolder & "\"
 Set objFSOUNCSearchFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set objFSOUNCSearchFolder2 = objFSOUNCSearchFolder.GetFolder(strCurrentFolder)
 Set colFolderList = objFSOUNCSearchFolder2.SubFolders

 'Subfolder dive
 For Each objFolder in colFolderList
  strSubFolder = objFolder.name
  'REMOVE THIS ECHO LATER
  wscript.echo strSubFolder
  UNCSearchFolder(strCurrentFolder, strSubFolder)
 Next

 'Search for files here


 'GC on File Streams
 Set objFSOUNCSearchFolder2 = Nothing
 Set objFSOUNCSearchFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

So, should one filestream be used for all accesses or should each step use one separately?  Is it a moot point?  Will this cause multiple connections to each system or should it only use one?  Basically I want the script to work without disrupting users, or causing weird responses (ie, running out of active connections).  The script will only be used a couple times for an audit we're doing, but may eventually be repurposed for future audits.

Let me know what you think.  Thanks for any help,

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most coders not consider to optimize FSO calls in recursion, therefore you got my upvote for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose to set a reference to FSO inside your function, 
then in each recursion will be used new FSO object.

Using single FSO object (either global, or passed) is quite enough. 
At least I don't know any benefit of using multiple FSO instances.

[EDIT] I appreciate @AnsgarWiechers comment, and to make the code ready for re-using, while kept the FSO out of the function, we can wrap our function in a class.

```
With New FileInfo
    WScript.Echo .FileSize("C:\temp", "txt", True)
End With


Class FileInfo

    Private m_oFSO

    Public Function FileSize(sRootDir, sExtension, bRecursive)
        Dim oFolder, oFile, sFExt
        sFExt = LCase(sExtension)
        Set oFolder = m_oFSO.GetFolder(sRootDir)
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            If LCase(m_oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = sFExt Then
                FileSize = FileSize + oFile.Size
            End If
        Next
        If bRecursive Then
            Dim oSubFolder
            For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
                FileSize = FileSize + FileSize(oSubFolder, sExtension, True)
            Next
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        Set m_oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate
        Set m_oFSO = Nothing
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Only reason I know of for not using a global `FileSystemObject` is to make a function self-contained (so it can be easily re-used in other scripts).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Good to know in the future, but after talking with one of my buddies, he made the argument for using WMI instead.  The problem is due to active connections; his thought is that multiple FSO will cause multiple active connections, causing timeouts (or, even using a single FSO, it might not close the connection to the last PC once it's done with it).  Still, this will work well when working with local paths.