# Excel VBA CMD to List Directory Contents

Tags: excel, vba, cmd

How would I modify this Excel VBA to:

1. List the paths of the directories and not just the files?
2. Filter out system and hidden files?

Here is the the current VBA:

```
Sub MM()
    Dim fResults As Variant
    fResults = GetFiles("C:\Temp")
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(fResults) + 1, 1).Value = _ 
    WorksheetFunction.Transpose(fResults)
End Sub


// UDF to populate array with files, assign to a Variant variable.
Function GetFiles(parentFolder As String) As Variant
    GetFiles = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & parentFolder & _
        IIf(Right(parentFolder, 1) = "\", vbNullString, "\") & "*.*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")
End Function
```

Comment: Is FSO not an option? you could get list of files and folders using that

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14911969/7599798 to see how to traverse through all subdirs using the FilesystemObject. Instead of counting the file sizes, you could fill a collection or dictionary.

Comment: I have a directory with almost 10,000 folders/files I want to list, and I found CMD markedly faster.

Comment: https://www.itprotoday.com/compute-engines/jsi-tip-3109-how-do-i-get-dir-command-show-system-and-hidden-files

Comment: Change the attributes argument of your `dir` command.

Comment: I changed attribute to "/A:-S" and that got rid of system files, but I cannot figure out how to list folders. It is only listing files.

Comment: Your `Filter … IIF …` construct is also removing the directories.  Get rid of it.  Something like `GetFiles = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & parentFolder & """ /A:-H-S /B /S").StdOut.ReadAll, vbNewLine)` might better do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Filter … IIF … construct is also removing the directories. Get rid of it. Something like

```
GetFiles = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & parentFolder & """ /A-H-S /B /S").StdOut.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
```

might better do what you want

Comment: Fantastic, Ron. Does exactly what I want. Is there a way to hide the CLI window when calling?

Comment: @BadDogTitan If you do an internet search, you'll find some ideas having to do with Windows API calls.  I've not been able to get them to work satisfactorily in the past, so I usually use the `.Run` method with the `xlHidden` argument; redirect the output to a temporary file; read the file using the `FileSystemObject`, then delete the file. You may have to make some adjustments if you have characters with code > 255 in your data.  IIRC correctly, you'll need a `\U` flag for the `CMD` call and with the `FSO` set `TristateTrue`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in changing the parameters for the dir command.

Use:

```
DIR /S /B /A-H-S
```

The -D currently specified hides the directories.
Full explanation of the dir parameters can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir